# Family of products of finitely maximal ideals has a minimal element

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/919815/15618) it is mentioned

> Consider now a minimal element in the family of products of finitely many maximal ideals, let it be $M_1 \ldots M_k$.

Why should the family of products have a minimal element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the answer, it says

> A finite dimensional (commutative or not) algebra over a field is an artinian ring, because it certainly satisfies the descending chain condition on left or right ideals.

The reason for this is that ideals are $K$-vector subspaces, and $\dim_KR$ is finite.

A ring is (left/right) artinian if and only if every non-empty family of (left/right) ideals has a minimal element.